# BitmapData from Flash to PHP to Email

Tags: php, flash, mime

**UPDATED: SEE BOTTOM OF MESSAGE**

Howdy All, Here's the issue:
I'm trying to take a 'screenshot' of a movieclip in Flash, encode it as a Jpg using the AS Core Lib JPGEncoder class, then POST submit it to PHP, and embed the image in a MIME encoded email.

Currently, I've tested saving the encoded image locally, and that works, so the encoder is definitely working. The email sends, and it has a 100kb jpg attachment as it should, however, the image appears to contain bad data, as it won't open properly in any application.

Here's the Actionscript:

```
trace("Sending Email");
    var rootMC:MovieClip = MovieClip(root);
    var data1:BitmapData = new BitmapData(rootMC.width, rootMC.height); 
    data1.draw(rootMC);

    var en:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(80);
    var bArray:ByteArray=   en.encode(data1);

var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");

    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
    request.requestHeaders.push(header);
    request.url = mailLoc;//MailLoc is the URL of the PHP.
    request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    request.data = bArray;
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, MailCompleteHandler);
    try
    {
        loader.load(request);
    }
    catch(error:Error)
    {
        trace("Unable to load URL");
    }
```

And here is the PHP:

```
require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';  
$image = file_get_contents("php://input");  
$attachment = SwiftAttachment::newInstance($image, 'submission.jpg', 'image/jpg');//<--This line stuffs it  

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()  
    /*Give the message a subject*/  
    ->setSubject('Your subject')  
    /*Set the from address with an associative array*/  
    ->setFrom(array('info@battleforbrisbane.com.au'=>'Battle for Brisbane'))  
    /*Set the to addresses with an associative array*/  
    ->setTo(array('jordaanm@gmail.com'))  
    /*Give it a body*/  
    ->setBody('Congratulations! You submission to Battle for Brisbane was received'); 
    $message->attach($attachment);//<--When the attachment above is commented out, so is this  

    $transport = Swift_SendmailTransport::newInstance();  
    $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);  
    $mailer->send($message);
```

Update: I'm now using [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) instead of manually writing out the MIME. However, here is the new deal: In the php code, I've marked a line that attaches the POSTed image data as a jpg to the email. If I comment out this line, and the message->attach line, then every sends fine. If they're uncommented, though, then no email is sent, which leads me to believe that trying to create a jpg attachment from the data supplied is causing the problem. 
This all just confirms my suspicions that the data being received by the PHP script is not correct. How nice and frustrating.

Comment: Since you can save the image on the server and view it, the problem isn't related to Flash, aside from chunk_split/base64 encoding what else is different when you save the image vs emailing it?  Have you tried the same emailing routine using a JPG saved on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should seriously consider [using a modern mail library like SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org) instead of building your own MIME headers and bodies.  As you are now aware, doing this correctly by hand can be a royal pain.

<s>You should also make sure that the data PHP is receiving is actually a bad image before assuming it's the mail that's going wrong.  Try saving the results of your `file_get_contents` to disk and viewing it in your browser, just to make sure.</s>

Comment: to quote the OP "Currently, I've tested saving the encoded image locally, and that works" ... Agreed that a library like SwiftMailer is a lot more straight forward and less error prone then rolling their own. +1

Comment: Using Swiftmailer now. Makes the code cleaner, but the image attachment issue prevails.

Comment: Can you upload a tiny image (how about a 1x1 pixel gif or png), send it out via mail, then post a link to the image and provide the complete raw source from the mail?

Comment: Also, in regards to Charles' strikeout point, I cannot save it on the server. I can save it locally from flash. I've tried using fwrite in the php script, but no file is ever output. Tres Annoying. It does pretty much confirm for me, though, that the issue is in the sending from Flash -> PHP

Comment: Took me a few tries, eventually figured out that I was missing an underscore in Swift_Attachment. Thankyou for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I'm slightly outside my comfort zone here, but I believe you may need to add some more header information.

Jonathan Marston has created a wrapper class to do this, which can be found here:
http://code.google.com/p/asfeedback/source/browse/trunk/com/marston/utils/URLRequestWrapper.as?spec=svn4&r=4#

Which you could try using in the following way:

```
var byteArray : ByteArray = new JPGEncoder( 80 ).encode( data1);
var wrapper = new URLRequestWrapper(byteArray, "submission.jpg");
wrapper.url = mailLoc;

var ldr:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
ldr.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
ldr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, MailCompleteHandler);
ldr.load(wrapper.request);
```