# BitmapData from Flash -> PHP -> Email

Tags: php, flash, mime

I'm trying to take a 'screenshot' of a movieclip in Flash, encode it as a Jpg using the AS Core Lib JPGEncoder class, then POST submit the resulting ByteArray to PHP, and embed the image in a MIME encoded email.

Currently, I've saved the encoded ByteArray from Flash, and that works fine, so the issue is in the sending from Flash to PHP.
I'm using SwiftMailer to send a complex email with the jpeg as an attachment. Currently, the script seems to be crashing at the point where I build the attachment from the sent data.

Here's the Actionscript:

```
trace("Sending Email");
    var rootMC:MovieClip = MovieClip(root);
    var data1:BitmapData = new BitmapData(rootMC.width, rootMC.height); 
    data1.draw(rootMC);

    var en:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(80);
    var bArray:ByteArray=   en.encode(data1);

var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");

    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
    request.requestHeaders.push(header);
    request.url = mailLoc;//MailLoc is the URL of the PHP.
    request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    request.data = bArray;
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, MailCompleteHandler);
    try
    {
        loader.load(request);
    }
    catch(error:Error)
    {
        trace("Unable to load URL");
    }
```

And here is the PHP:

```
require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';  
$image = file_get_contents("php://input");  
$attachment = SwiftAttachment::newInstance($image, 'submission.jpg', 'image/jpg');//<--This line stuffs it  

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()  
    /*Give the message a subject*/  
    ->setSubject('Your subject')  
    /*Set the from address with an associative array*/  
    ->setFrom(array('info@battleforbrisbane.com.au'=>'Battle for Brisbane'))  
    /*Set the to addresses with an associative array*/  
    ->setTo(array('jordaanm@gmail.com'))  
    /*Give it a body*/  
    ->setBody('Congratulations! You submission to Battle for Brisbane was received'); 
    $message->attach($attachment);//<--When the attachment above is commented out, so is this  

    $transport = Swift_SendmailTransport::newInstance();  
    $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);  
    $mailer->send($message);
```

This is for a professional job, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update: It's not SwiftAttachment, it's Swift_Attachment. Missing underscore, problem solved, application functional. Thanks to all who posted to help me with this**

Comment: This seems to be [an exact duplicate of your question yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399235/bitmapdata-from-flash-to-php-to-email).  I'd still love to see the raw output of a 1x1 GIF, though over there, not here.

Comment: This is a refined version of the question yesterday. Some of the minor issues were solved by yourself (using SwiftMailer now instead of manually encoding). However, the big issue is not finished. In terms of the 1x1 pixel, any data I send across from Flash->PHP refuses to write (fwrite) or mime attach.

Comment: Does `$image` have a `strlen`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the issue all along was that I was missing an underscore in Swift_Attachment. Don't you just hate that?

Comment: Right, that sucks. But with a proper "debug" methodology it would have been easy to isolate the offending code. Basically, break the whole thing into smaller tasks, test one, then build the next one on top. When the current task fails, you know where you can focus.

Answer (score 2):

Have you verified that the encoded image is a valid one?

If you have a local server or a different server try it there.

Also, you can try to load one image into your flash and send that to the server and see if that works, instead of sending a generated image.

As for how to send the image from flash, try this

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest( mailLoc );
request.contentType = 'application/octet-stream';
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
request.data = bArray;

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, MailCompleteHandler);
loader.addEventListener( IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, _onImageError );
try
{
    loader.load(request);
}
catch(error:Error)
{
    trace("Unable to load URL");
}


private function _onImageError(e:IOErrorEvent):void {
    trace("IOErrorEvent: ",e.type," : ",e.text) 
}
```

And for the php script, you can try first to save the file.

```
//bindary data.
$image_bytes = $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"];
//change to whatever works for you
$file_name = "testfile.jpg";
$file_path = "../uploads/$file_name";

$file = fopen( $file_path, 'w+' );

if ( !fwrite( $file, $image_bytes ) ) {
    return "Error writing to file: $file";
}

fclose( $file );
```

Comment: Thanks for the that goliatone. I made the changes you suggested. No flags are being raised for IO Issues on Flash's end. For some reason, the PHP script doesn't write the file. Odd...

Comment: Did you try in a different PHP set up? Or sending an image that you uploaded previously instead of a generated one?